# Terminal tab not opening in same directory

Tags: 14.04, gnome-terminal

Since upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04 whenever I open a new Tab in the Terminal I am in the Home directory instead of the directory I was in in the other Tab.

How can I change it to stay in the directory from the Tab I opened it from?

Comment: Read [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93476/gnome-terminal-keep-track-of-directory-in-new-tab), may be this is a bug

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you are dealing with [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-gnome/+bug/1193993). You will find there in the [comment #2](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-gnome/+bug/1193993/comments/2) the following workaround (thanks to [Tim (darkxst)](https://launchpad.net/%7Edarkxst) for it):

> add the following line to the end of `~/.bashrc` file:
>
> ```
> . /etc/profile.d/vte.sh
> ```

Comment: Hm this doesn't work for me in Ubuntu 15.10 with zsh (and changing .zshrc)

Answer (score 1):

The

```
. /etc/profile.d/vte.sh
```

workaround did not work for me. However, what did work is: I finally discovered that in the Profile Preferences' "Command" tab (right click in the terminal->Profiles) unchecking "Run a custom command instead of my shell", if it is checked, can also solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

In 16.04 a symlink may be missing. The file can be found at `/etc/profile.d/vte-2.91.sh`

[Source](https://github.com/gnunn1/tilix/wiki/VTE-Configuration-Issue#1-source-vtesh-in-bashrc)